# Looking for: IntelliJ IDEA plugin with BeanShell syntax support

Tags: intellij-idea, beanshell

I was wondering if there is a plugin to support the [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/home.html) scripting framework in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)? Setting the ***.bsh** file type as a Java source causes all sort of bad syntax warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the [BeanShell Box](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1022) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing BeanShell plug-ins for IDEA. A skillful developer with enough passion [could create one](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA).